# Npgsql with PostgreSQL: Can't see uncommitted changes with UNCOMMITTED READ

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I'm using Npsql with PostgreSQL. I want to see uncommitted changes of one transaction in a different one.

This is how I create my connection and transaction:

```
// create connection
m_Connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
m_Connection.Open();

//create transaction
m_Transaction = m_Connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
```

In one thread I insert a row like so:

```
 NpgsqlCommand command = CreateCommand("INSERT INTO TABLEA  ....", parameters, commandTimeout)
 command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and process something else without committing or rolling back the transaction.

In a different thread I read a row like so:

```
 NpgsqlCommand command = CreateCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLEA", parameters, commandTimeout);
 command.ExecuteScalar();
```

but somehow I don't see the results of the first INSERT. I don't see the results of the insert in pgAdmin either (even after running SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED).

What am I doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not support uncommitted reads.

You will never be able to see changes from other transactions that are not committed.

Comment: Wow. This is a surprise to me. Thanks for the answer! :) More info for the interested here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-set-transaction.html ("In PostgreSQL READ UNCOMMITTED is treated as READ COMMITTED, while REPEATABLE READ is treated as SERIALIZABLE.")

Comment: Why is that surprising? READ UNCOMMITTED does not really make sense (at least to me)

Comment: It's surprising to me personally because I used to work with DB2 where READ UNCOMMITTED was a valid isolation level. And it is also defined in the SQL standard.

Comment: @machinery: from my experience read uncommitted is usually a workaround for engines (older DB2, older SQL Server), that rely on heavy locking to shield the different transactions. In that case allowing uncommitted reads seems to be the only way to get out of the lock "trap". DBMS that have MVCC like PostgreSQL or Oracle never needed that.

Comment: @machinery: You cited version 8.1 docs, a version which is quite old and out of support. There is now a difference between `REPEATABLE READ` and `SERIALIZABLE` transaction isolation levels, starting with version 9.1. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/transaction-iso.html

Comment: @kgrittn thanks for the info :) I blindly opened whatever google returned first.

Comment: Latest version of Npgsql supports sending the correct isolation command when running on Postgresql server which supports it. Please try it again and let me know if it works for you.